# angular $watch - can't get watch to fire when set is same variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to send some variables between controllers with angular's $watch and a factory. It works great however I am trying to be able to send an error message if the user tries to add the same thing twice. With the way it is working now  - the user has to switch off the value and back onto it to send the error message out. I believe this is because it has a watch on the function and the set function is sending the same variable so it's technically not changing so the watch is not firing - let me show you what I mean.

My factory looks like so  -

```
.service("multiPromptFactory",function(){

var msg = "";
var msg2 = "";
return {
        setType: function(x) {
            msg=x; 
        },
        getType: function() {
            return msg;
        },
        setFading: function(y) {
            msg2=y; 
        },
        getFading: function() {
            return msg2;
        }
    };
})
```

And so In one controller I set the value with this -

```
  multiPromptFactory.setType(item);
```

And in another controller I listen to the factory like so -

```
$scope.$watch(multiPromptFactory.getType,function(typeHere){
      //add new prompt type when this fires
        $scope.storeTempName = typeHere;
                var addBlock= true;
                      for (var i=0; i<$scope.blocksHere.length; i++){
                        if($scope.blocksHere[i].typeId == $scope.storeTempName.id){
                            //already exists - fire warning for user
                            addBlock= false;
                        }
                      }
                      if(addBlock){
                        //doesn't exist yet, allow user to add 
                    }
    });
```

This works great, however I would like to send an error message when the user send the same value - it seems watch doesn't fire if the variable never changes, even if it's sent again. I am wondering if there is some way to tell the watch function to fire every time, even if the variable sent is the same. Or maybe I just need to approach this differently? Input would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

you have to copy value in order to fire `$watch` like this:

```
.service("multiPromptFactory",function(){
    var msg = "";
    var msg2 = "";
    return {
            setType: function(x) {
                msg=x; 
            },
            getType: function() {
                return angular.copy(msg);
            },
            setFading: function(y) {
                msg2=y; 
            },
            getFading: function() {
                return msg2;
            }
        };
    })
```

Comment: This will cause the watch to fire on _every_ digest cycle. May or may not be what the OP wants, and moreover, there's an easier way to do it: just `$scope.$watch(function() { ... whatever ...});`.

Comment: `$scope.$watch(function() { ... whatever ...});` but this will track all changes in scope,right?

Comment: i think, if your code need to be fired on the changing with same values you better rewrite it